# ¿Qué significa "tiene mucho down" en la letra de "Woman del Callao"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado, letras-de-canciones, venezuela, república-dominicana

[Juan Luis Guerra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Luis_Guerra) es un artista dominicano, aunque la canción *Woman del Callao* está dedicada a una (¿la?) mujer del Callao, en Venezuela. El estribillo dice tal que así:

> Tiene mucho hot
>   tiene mucho tempo
>   y tiene mucho down

Es de esas letras que aquí aceptamos sin más, sin preocuparnos mucho por el significado, dado que suelen sonar en fiestas o salas de baile y la intención principal de la misma es mover el cuerpo. Sin embargo, si nos paramos a analizar la letra ya me entra la curiosidad. ¿Qué quiere decir que una mujer tenga mucho *tempo* y mucho *down*?

Entiendo como *tener tempo* el tener ritmo. Sin embargo *tener down* me descuadra dado que, [según la Asale](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=down), en Venezuela *down* se usa en el sentido de "estar deprimido" y especialmente "por el consumo de drogas". Sin embargo, en [la letra de la canción](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=124117) no hay nada que haga pensar que el tema de la canción sea ese.

Así pues, ¿qué interpretación se le da a decir que una mujer "tiene tempo" y "tiene down" en Venezuela y/o la República Dominicana?

Comment: No conocía esta canción y me ha hecho bailar un rato jeje. Interesante también la palabra _apambichao_ que menciona más adelante.

Comment: @fedorqui que no te creas que no me he fijado en esa palabra, da para otra pregunta...

Comment: @fedorqui "[apampichado, -a](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=apampichado)": RD. Referido a persona, que baila muy pegada a su pareja, apretándola. Efectivamente, es propia de la República Dominicana.

Comment: ¡Qué buena! Puede que venga de [_pichar_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=kfBgLWY8Yx0ALLzynX8) que define como _Molestar continuamente a una persona, hacer que se enoje_, también en RD.

Comment: Urban dictionary menciona un montón de definiciones "alternativas" para _down_. Por ejemplo, la definen como ["ligera"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=down&defid=1632503) o [animada / dispuesta](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=down&defid=2053811), aunque tengo la sensación que más que "down" es el "tener down" lo que le da más significado. En [este hilo](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hunt-y-down.732537/) de word reference no veo demasiada chicha.

Comment: Puede ser una referencia al ["downtown"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downtown_music) como estilo musical? Como "tener mucho feeling"?

Comment: Aunque la mayoría de las canciones de Guerra están escritas por él, esta es una versión de un artista venezolano, Julio Delgado. De ahí el tema.

Comment: Down = cadencia (caída) = ritmo
A mi modo de ver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las expresiones "**Tener *down***" o "tener *tempo*" tienen un sentido particular dentro del contexto de los raperos/reggaetoneros latinos y vienen a significar algo así como "**tener ritmo**", utilizándose normalmente para presumir, como tener "*flow*" (fluidez al rapear o cantar) o tener "*swag*" (buena ropa/apariencia).

Referencia de ejemplo:

> *Tengo el down, que sería el trotar del hip-hop, y lo pongo a funcionar con bossa nova: el híbrido no tiene swing pero la letra es una visión infantil de la década de los 70, a través de un desfile de granaderos.*
>
> (http://www.rollingstone.com.ar/584958-andres-calamaro)

Ejemplos en canciones:

> *Pa estar pegao
>
> Hay que tener down*
>
> https://www.musixmatch.com/es/letras/Gente-de-Zona/Pinocho
>
> *Que a mí me gusta el down y el toma traka*
>
> https://m.letras.com/haze/1346264/
>
> *Soy Aloy me presento
>
> tengo tempo tengo furia*
>
> http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1624770

Comment: tener flow se refiere a la habilidad (literalmente cuanto fluyes al rapear), tener swag al estilo. Mal ejemplo clarificador