# ¿Qué significa "apambichao"?

Tags: significado, diferencias-regionales, letras-de-canciones, música, república-dominicana

Esta pregunta nace de un comentario debajo de [una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20049/9385) acerca de la terminología musical usada en la [canción  *Woman del Callao*](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=124117) de [Juan Luis Guerra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Luis_Guerra), un artista dominicano. Una parte de la letra dice tal que así (aproximadamente a 4:32 de la grabación):

> Tiene mucho hot
>   Mucho tempo
>   Woman pá aquí, woman pá allá
>   Woman de lao, **apambichao**.

Supongo que "lao" será *lado* (meneo de la cadera), pero ¿qué quiere decir "apambichao"?

Comment: Esperaba que alguien hiciera esta pregunta, después de que su respuesta apareciera en la que hice en su día. ¡Gracias por animarte!

Comment: @Charlie - Fue un placer.  Últimamente no se me han occurrido preguntas....  Pero ahora no sé cómo proceder.  Levanto un flag en la respuesta para que se migre para acá?  No sé si existe la migración de respuestas.

Comment: No existe, justo estaba por preguntarlo (no sé si en Meta o en el Stack de moderadores).

Comment: @fedorqui - ¿Aún puedes borrar una pregunta *spam*?  (No sé si Charlie estará en línea pronto....)

Comment: Suelo estar en línea con cierta frecuencia, el problema es que desde la aplicación móvil las opciones de moderación son muy limitadas. Ayer vi la segunda pregunta _spam_ apenas 30 minutos después de que la publicaran y pude eliminarla, la primera parece que la comunidad se encargó de ello (gracias). En todo caso procuraré acceder desde un portátil al menos una vez al día (como ahora) para ir quitándome flags de moderación de encima.

Comment: @fedorqui - De acuerdo con todo lo que dijiste. // Por curiosidad, fedorqui, ¿ya saliste del periodo de transición, en cuanto a las functiones de moderación?

Comment: @fedorqui - ¿Entendí mal?  Creí que en un principio estabas esperando que los CM cambiaran algo, y mientras tanto, todavía tenías algunas de las funciones -- si bien no las usabas.

Comment: @fedorqui - Sí, claro que sí.  Ah, bien, con 15 días ya terminó tu suspensión.  Gracias por aclarar.  // Espero que en año nuevo tengamos más moderadores, para que no esté toda la responsibilidad sobre Charlie.

Comment: @fedorqui - Ay ay ay, me expresé mal.  Perdón, quise decir con 15 días ya terminó tu transición.

Answer (score 5):

Seguramente haya algún dominicano que nos pueda aportar las connotaciones agregadas a la palabra  **apambichao**,  que representa una [variedad rítmica del Merengue típico (o Perico ripiao, coloquialmente) de República Dominicana](https://sites.google.com/site/teconologiasmigdalia/el-pampiche)

> Para varios autores el "merengue apambichao" o pambiche tuvo su origen en Puerto Plata hacia 1917.
>   Se dice que es un tipo de merengue desarrollado durante la primera ocupación militar norteamericana, entre los años 1916 y 1924, como una imitación a los frustrados intentos de los estadounidenses por no poder bailar de forma correcta en las fiestas a las cuales asistían frecuentemente, creando los dominicanos un paso de baile llamado merengue yanqui, acompañado de un nuevo ritmo de tambora y una canción con letras sobre una fábrica de Palm Beach.
> En referencia a la ciudad de La Florida surge el nombre de llamar al ritmo Pambiche, derivado de la pronunciación de "Palm Beach", como forma de liberar la humillación política sufrida por los dominicanos ante la ocupación extranjera.

Lo que está además reflejado en [esta fuente de Wikipedia (en inglés)](https://sites.google.com/site/teconologiasmigdalia/el-pampiche)

> Pambiche or merengue ***apambichao** is said to have developed during the American occupation of the Dominican Republic (1916–1924), taking its name from the "Palm Beach" fabric worn by American soldiers. Its tempo is usually slower than merengue derecho, and it can be recognized by the more syncopated rhythms in both bass and tambora. It is probably the rhythm most beloved by típico aficionados: dancing to it is said to require more skill since it is more complicated and syncopated than merengue derecho, and it helps to set the típico genre apart since it is used infrequently by orquesta groups.

En este video puede verse la [demostración](https://youtu.be/4AIXO5FKOgY) hecha por un señor acerca de la manera de ejecutar el ritmo sobre un tambor

Comment: Interesantísimo. Referencia: [Ocupación estadounidense de la República Dominicana (1916-1924)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocupación_estadounidense_de_la_República_Dominicana_(1916-1924))

Answer (score 2):

Respondo como dominicana.
El adjetivo apambichado creo que existe.
Es bailar pegado, casi sin vueltas y la pareja baila pegadita (entonces van como enamorados bailando y disfrutando el contacto cuerpo a cuerpo). Más bueno que es bailar asi. El ritmo es más lento tambien. Debe ser merengue que se preste para bailar pegado y no muy rápido.

Comment: Sabrosura de comentario, @user34179 gracias por escribirlo. Entonces estar "apambichao" para ustedes los dominicanos es estar en un baile "pegados" bailando despacito y románticamente bajo un ritmo o compás lento, ¿verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Apambichado es un término del merengue que se creó cuando los soldados de la Marina de Guerra de los EEUU estaban en la República Dominicana, previo a los tiempos de la dictadura de Trujillo. El merengue era demasiado rápido para los soldados estadounidenses. Así que se creó una versión más lenta para que los norteamericanos, que eran de la flota de Palm Beach, Florida pudieran bailar. De ‘Palm Beach’ salió la palabra ‘apambichado’.

Comment: Gracias, Charlie, pero lo inconveniente es que José no haya recibido crédito por su respuesta, y que no pueda leer el comentario que le dejé.

Comment: @aparente001 esa era mi intención, le he dado un tiempo de margen para que moviera la respuesta y se llevara el crédito, antes de mover la respuesta yo mismo. Al ser un usuario no registrado dudaba de que leyera los mensajes.